# JBoss 5.1: Entity classes not found (vfszip)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jboss

I am using JBoss 5.1 with Hibernate 3.6, **JPA 2.0** and Spring 3.0.5.
I use maven to build the EAR file which looks like :

```
AutoTrader.ear 
-------> META-INF
--------------> application.xml
--------------> jboss-app.xml
--------------> MANIFEST.MF
-------> AutoTrader.war
```

if I deploy this ear file in JBoss 5.1, i get the error

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Not an entity: class uk.co.aol.shipmanager.domain.Manager; nested exception is ja
va.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class uk.co.aol.shipmanager.domain.Subscription
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:286) ~[at_war-1.0.war:3
.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:104) ~[at_war-1.0.war:3.0.5.RELEASE
]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:368) ~[at_war-1.
0.war:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:58
) ~[at_war-1.0.war:3.0.5.RELEASE]
```

However, if I deploy the war file exploded, it works fine.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks,
Adi

**UPDATE:**

I have added a ResourceScanner which extends NativeScanner:

```
public class ResourceScanner extends NativeScanner {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClassesInJar(final URL jarToScan,
            final Set<Class<? extends Annotation>> annotationsToLookFor) {
        return super.getClassesInJar(patchUrl(jarToScan), annotationsToLookFor);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<NamedInputStream> getFilesInJar(final URL jarToScan, final Set<String> filePatterns) {
        return super.getFilesInJar(patchUrl(jarToScan), filePatterns);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Package> getPackagesInJar(final URL jarToScan,
            final Set<Class<? extends Annotation>> annotationsToLookFor) {
        return super.getPackagesInJar(patchUrl(jarToScan), annotationsToLookFor);
    }

    @Override
    public String getUnqualifiedJarName(final URL jarToScan) {
        return super.getUnqualifiedJarName(patchUrl(jarToScan));
    }

    /**
     * Patch the VFS URL to a FILE protocol URL.
     * 
     * @param url
     *            original URL.
     * @return either the original, either the corresponding FILE protocol of given VFS URL.
     */
    protected URL patchUrl(final URL url) {
        String protocol = url.getProtocol();

        if (protocol.equals("vfs")) {
            try {
                File file = new File(url.getFile());
                return file.toURI().toURL();
            } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
                return url;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return url;
            }

        }
        return url;
    }
}
```

and, in spring-persistence.xml,

```
<property name="hibernate.ejb.resource_scanner" value="uk.co.aol.shipmanager.ResourceScanner"/>
```

This again works in the exploded war file.

**But in case of a *EAR* file, the protocol is *vfszip* not *vfs*.**

Please tell what to do???

Comment: It sounds like the exploded ear works because it can find the dependent jar files. I think with an EAR you have to either reference those in the classpath of the manifest file, or maybe the application.xml file. It sounds like a classpath issue, or maybe it's a deployment order issue. If the class looking for the entity deploying first when in an EAR, but maybe the exploded version deploys in a different order. That is an issue sometimes, so check your dependencies and see if you can define them in an EAR.

Comment: What's the layout of the WAR? Do you have a persistence.xml? Have you annotated the Manager and Subscription classes with @Entity (or provided appropriate XML config).  Third party JARs should go in a WARs WEB-INF/lib or and EARs lib dir.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried to to use the following system parameter and see if it helped resolved the issue?

```
-Dorg.jboss.net.protocol.file.useURI=false
```